# Pass a URL in a GET for PHP

Tags: php, url, get

I need to pass a url using a GET address. To give an example which was I have tried:

```
http://www.example.com/area/#http://www.example.com/area2/
```

I've also tried replacing the forward slashes with other characters but that doesn't seem to work. How would you pass a url in a GET?

Comment: urlencode & urldecode may help?

Comment: Note, anything after a `#`, the server should never see.  (I've heard stories about Firefox passing it, but the RFCs say it's meant to be strictly client-side.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I have understood, you should use [`url_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) and [`url_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php).

The function [`url_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) lets you create a string that can be used as a link.

You should use it this way:

```
$link = 'goto.php?link=' . url_encode($_POST['target_site']);
```

And when you were going to redirect to the user defined site (eg), you can decode the parameter given this way:

```
$decoded_link = url_decode($_GET['link']);
// Now it's safe to use the given URL (for example I can redirect to there)
header('location: ' . $decoded_link);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The `#` character links to an anchor on the page. The browser will automatically scroll to the element with the id after the point sign. So that's not what you're looking for.

To pass a GET parameter, the syntax would be like this:

http://example.com/area?http://example.com/area2

Then, if you `var_dump($_GET)`, you'll see your URL. But, if you have other fields you also want to pass in your URL, you can use key=value pairs, like so:

http://example.com/area?url=http://example.com/area2&param1=a&param2=b

In this case, your URL will be available in `$_GET['url']`.

Comment: Well I am using an htaccess file like this RewriteRule ^login/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$   /login.php?url=$1 [PT,L,QSA]